# css for footer text

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm having a hard time with a simple css snippet for footer text.
The footer text must always be at the end of the page **and** the end of the screen whatever comes later.

Comment: The end of the page *and* the end of the screen? Won't 'at the end of the page' be sufficient based on that?  If the page runs off the bottom of the screen then the footer would be at the bottom of the page (ie: not visible on screen). If you scroll to the bottom of the page then the footer would still be at the bottom of the page but visible on screen... Maybe a code example of what you're trying to achieve might prevent me from tying my mind in logical knots... :)

Comment: if the page is very short (just occupies half of the screen), then I still want the footer to be at the bottom of the screen, and not and the middle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
* {
    margin: 0;
}
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    height: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto -142px; /* the bottom margin is the negative value of the footer's height */
}
.footer, .push {
    height: 142px; /* .push must be the same height as .footer */
}

/*

Sticky Footer by Ryan Fait
http://ryanfait.com/

*/
```

Answer (score 0):

For a working example which you could pick apart I had previously done this exact same thing for a client of ours:

[Pushed Down Page](http://lvdesigncenter.com/about/overview) -
[Fixed Position Page](http://lvdesigncenter.com/events/private)

Answer (score -1):

Use the `bottom` property:

```
#footer
{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:2px;
}
```

Comment: This would position it at the bottom of the viewport. If the page was longer it would not be at the bottom of the page (which the question specific).

Comment: It would, if the body tag has position: relative;

Comment: @David yes it would - did you try it? I've used it on several projects. See http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pos_bottom.asp